# RecylerView modify single view

Tags: android, android-viewholder, android-recyclerview

In the new Android RecyclerView has someone a way to access and modify the single views based on the position ?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleHourAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    viewHolder.txtStunde.setText(input[position]);
}
```

onBindViewHolder I can access the ViewHolder and position, but not the View populated by the ViewHolder.

And onCreateViewHolder I can access the view but I do not have the position of this view.

```
// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, null);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ...
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the `View` from the `ViewHolder` using:

```
View view = viewHolder.itemView;
```